# What is the proper/formal names for these rooms?

Tags: single-word-requests

Question 1:
We just moved into a new house with a very unique layout. I'm wondering how to describe some of the rooms using formal definitions.

The main floor has an open-air space that is pretty versatile — it could be a living room, or it could be a dining room, we haven't decided ourselves yet — and extends upwards two floors.

The term [*atrium*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/atrium) seems to fit as there are windows that go up one whole side of the area, but I wasn't sure if that term was traditionally reserved for non-residential uses.

[*Great room*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/great+room) also seems to apply, though it's not necessarily a vaulted ceiling and therefore doesn't fit Wikipedia's definition.

What is the difference between an atrium and a great room, or is there another word that would describe this room more formally?

Question 2:
The upper level of our house contains three separate areas — a landing/den, a wide space used as a bedroom in the past, and another space that is currently my office. These upper rooms are bordered by a half-wall on the sides that face the great room/atrium/whatever.

This area seems too big/complex to be considered simply a *loft*. Is there another term to describe it?

Comment: Thank you for joining English Language and Usage. It sounds like you have a lovely new home, but I'm afraid your question is not on-topic per the guidelines in our [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq). You are asking several questions in one post, which makes it difficult to determine what a correct answer might be. We would be happy to entertain such questions as "What is the difference between a great room and an atrium?"

Comment: @Kit: It's a tough call. Really, Chrisbloom7 has only two questions: terms for two spaces in his house. I'm sure this could fit nicely under the terminology tag.

Comment: Thanks Jimi, and yes - I'm just trying to find the proper english words for rooms that match what I described. I figured this might be a good forum, especially since there is no architectural focused SE site at the moment. If you disagree, I will close the question though I would appreciate if you could leave it up in the short term to see if anyone has an answer.

Comment: @Jimi @Chris I understand your reasoning and I am inclined to agree, but I still think this should be broken into two questions.

Comment: @Kit - I edited the question to remove some of the extraneous details and instead focus on the specific question. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @Chris That does help, but I still think two separate questions (one for each room) would be better. I'll suggest some edits for each, but it would be up to you to post a second question if you so desire.

Comment: I have had a long-term interest in architecture, so I find your question very interesting and I can totally visualize the structure from your excellent description. Many journals/magazines I've read would describe your living space simply as a two-storey living area/room. You could call it a great room, [great] hall...yeah, an atrium is definitely less domestic. The upper-level could also be called a gallery...

Comment: @Chris If you don't like these edits, you call use the rollback to removed them.

Comment: @Jimi - thanks for the info, I could live with that if posted as an answer :)

Comment: @Kit - my only problem with separating the questions is that the area described in the second half relies on the description of the area from the first half. If I separated out the second half then I would also have to post most of the description of the area (with the as of yet undefined room). So basically I would just be cutting this first question in half, then reposting most of the info to a new question. Sorry, not trying to be argumentative, just practical.

Comment: @Chris Fair enough.  Let's hope @Jimi is coming up with a really good answer for you!

Comment: Seriously folks? I thought we went through this already...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Part 1

Atriums or atria come from ancient Roman architecture. They were central to the house, occupied a couple stories and provided access to other rooms. See [The Roman House](http://www.roman-empire.net/society/soc-house.html) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atrium_%28architecture%29). These days, atria are common features of multi-story public structures, with huge windows and sky views. ([Here](http://www.roman-empire.net/society/soc-house.html) is an example of the famous Schow Atrium at Williams College.)

According to the [NOAD](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/great+room?region=us), the great room is

> a large room in a modern house that combines features of a living room with those of a dining room or family room.

In [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_room) Wikipedia article, there is an excellent photograph of a two-story great room.

In your house, *great room* would be the ideal term for the space you describe. You say it is a versatile space, one that would combine living and dining. The term would even be more apt if that is the only living space on the lower floor. *[Foyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foyer)* wouldn't work because your space primarily a living area. Also, *living room*, *family room* and *drawing room* are not adequate. However, *[front room](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_room)* is a completely acceptable term, as well.

The difference between an atrium and a great room in modern architecture would be thus: An atrium is a large open multistory space often found in public buildings functioning as the central access point to the rest of the building, a source of natural light and a multi-purpose space. A great room, however, is the main living area in a residential building, and it used for entertainment, relaxation, dining, etc.

It is possible that *atrium* may come full circle and regain its original usage in residential architecture. For now, however, the trend favors an industrial usage.

#### Part 2

A [loft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loft) is not always a simple structure. These days, converted lofts and loft apartments are all the rage, especially in cities where real estate is scarce. From what you describe, the three upper-level areas constitute a loft.

The area could also be a modified *gallery* of sorts, most especially because it has a "half-wall" that overlooks the living area. Galleries, however, are traditionally narrow. Here is the relevant definition from NOAD:

> a balcony, especially a platform or upper floor, projecting from the back or sidewall inside a church or hall, providing space for an audience or musicians.

*[Attic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attic)* should be ruled out, as it usually refers to an uninhabitable or unfinished space. *[Garret](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/garret?region=us)* is a fancy, old term that has a negative connotation. These two terms are inappropriate for the simple reason that your upper level *overlooks* the lower one in a way. Thus, *loft* and *gallery* are the best choices.

The bottom-line is: you can name the spaces in your house any way you want. For me, *atrium* and *gallery* go well together, because it makes sense that a gallery overlooks an atrium. *Great room* and *loft* are more traditional ("proper/formal") names, and these also go well together.

Themes can also be used in naming rooms in a house. For instance, the designer or owner yacht-themed house might favor the terms *galley*, for the kitchen, and *bridge* for an upper-level that overlooks the lower level on both sides (but this is a digression).

If you fancied them, you could term these spaces the *lounge* and the *garret*, depending on the look and feel (either real or imagined) of your house!

Comment: Oke has explained it perfectly.  Typical advertisingese would include phrases like "architectural **open-plan** living" and "open volumes" and the like.

Comment: Excellent answers, Jimi, and thank you for providing so much background information. I'm inclined to lean more towards the latter set of terms you provide.

Comment: @Chris: no problem. I'm glad we could save the question!

Comment: Well, I guess not!

Comment: Oh, well. Thanks for the answer to my "question" :)

Comment: @Jasper: back in the day, that's what I wanted to be. Now, I find myself leaning more toward the structural art.

Comment: @Chris: you're welcome. And perusing *Architectural Digest* and *Better Homes & Gardens* may give you a few more ideas...